# textarea replace code with pix and turn link into hyperlink and eventually do tag on username all in textarea

Tags: php, html

I have dilemma here, I'm building on my site and now on my commment post I want to do three things

1. grab tags of username which I'm not workin on now but later.
2. replace code with image.
3. Grab link which is in textarea and make it hyperlink.

Now 2 and 3 works perfect just not together and eventually I want all three working within textarea. Can this even be done by combine them three together? or would I have to take another approach.

```html
$textcode = array('[anarchy]','O:-)','X(','[anon]','=D>','~X(',';;)',':D','>:D<',
                  ':">','=((','[bullshit]',':-c',':O)',':-/','B-)','<):)',':((', 
                  '#-o','8->','>:)',':-$','=P~','[fuckyou]','[fuckyou2]',':)',
                  ':!!','@-)','X_X','^#(^',':-*',':))',':^o','L-)',':x',':-SS',
                  ':-B','[nobullshit]','[-(',':)]','<:-P','>:P',':ar!','[/||\]',
                  '/:)','\m/','8-|','=))',':(',':-&',':-<','8-}','I-)',':>',
                  ':|',':-O','=;',':-?',':-q',':-bd',':-t',':P',':-w',':-h',
                  '#:-S',';)',':-S','(:|');
      

$smileys = array('<img src="icon/anarchy.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/angel.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/angry.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/anonymous.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/applause.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/at wits end.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/batting eyelashes.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/big grin.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/big hug.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/blushing.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/broken heart.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/bullshit.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/call me.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/clown.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/confused.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/cool.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/cowboy.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/crying.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/doh.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/day dreaming.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/devil.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/dont tell anyone.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/drooling.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/fuckyou.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/fuckyou2.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/Happy.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/hurry up.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/hypnotized.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/I dont want to see.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/it wasnt me.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/kiss.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/laughting.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/liar.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/loaser.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/love struck.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/nail biting.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/nerd.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/nobullshit.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/not talking.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/on the phone.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/party.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/phbbbbt.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/pirate.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/pray.png" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/raised eyebrows.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/rock on.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/rolling eyes.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/rolling on the floor.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/sad.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/sick.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/sigh.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/silly.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/sleepy.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/smug.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/straight face.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/surprise.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/talk to the hand.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/thinking.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/thumbs down.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/thumbs up.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/time out.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/tongue.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/waiting.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/wave.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/whew.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/winking.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">', 
                 '<img src="icon/worried.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">','<img src="icon/yawn.gif" style="height:50px; width:50px;">');
 
 

$newData = str_replace($textcode,$smileys,$_POST['ta']);  //This will replace keywords with image 

  $url = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
$newDatas = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $newData); //This will grab link and make it hyperlink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url matching has too many optional elements and grabs everything that is at least partially valid url. The collision would arise for something like `worried.gif` because it will be treated as domain name.

My suggestion is to limit url detection with `whitespace|start`+ `protocol|www` as required alternative. I assumed the remaining regex part is fine (I just removed unneccessary capturing groups), so it goes like this:

```
$url = '@\s(?:http(s)?://|(www\.))((?:[a-zA-Z])(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?:[^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
$newDatas = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$1://$2$3" target="_blank" title="$2$3">$2$3</a>', $newData);
```

BTW. Smileys replacement have some issues - check this out:

```
$string = ':))';
$x = str_replace([':)', ':))'], ['smiley', 'big-smiley'], $string);
```

Comment: I agree: make sure the smileys are sorted in a suitable way before using them in the `str_replace()` function. The interference with your URL-replacement can probably be avoided by doing that first.

Answer (score 0):

If I knew I would figure it out after few weeks I won't never post the question; however, few days of break with new fresh eyes on it and I got it. thanks for help. Thank you for the post.

```html
<?php

   $url = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
$newData = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $_POST['ta']);

   $handle = fopen($myfile, 'a+');   
   //fwrite($handle,  '<fieldset><legend>Anonymous: ' . $date . '</legend>' . $newData . '</fieldset></br>');
   fwrite($handle, str_replace($textcode,$smileys,$newData) . '</br>');
   fclose($handle);
?>
```